# how to covert string array to char**

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to send the values manually here

```
void processArgs(int argc, char** argv);
```

if I sending like this

```
char* cwd[] = {"./comDaemon", "--loggg=pluginFramework:debug"};

parser->processArgs(2, cwd);
```

compiler showing warning as

warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

```
 char* cwd[] = {"./comDaemon", "--loggg=pluginFramework:debug"};
```

Comment: You want `const char* cwd[]`

Comment: And then you want `const char **argc)` in `processArgs()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Others have noted that the problem is you're trying to pass string literals (which are const) to a function that takes a non-const `char **` argument.  If what you want is to create non-const strings that you can pass to your non-const arg function, you need explicit char arrays (which you can initialize with string literals):

```
char arg0[] = "./comDaemon";
char arg1[] = "--loggg=pluginFramework:debug";
char *cwd[] = { arg0, arg1 };
```

you could even do this all on one line:

```
char arg0[] = "./comDaemon", arg1[] = "--loggg=pluginFramework:debug", *cwd[] = { arg0, arg1 };
```

Comment: That's really nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the function you're passing `cwd` to expects `char **` argument, instead of `const char **`, here is one way:

```
    char *cwd[] = { const_cast<char *>("value1"), const_cast<char *>("value2") };
```

Comment: Please consider user207421's comment. Otherwise, option 1 will give compilation error.

Comment: @KunalPuri Edited my post, see my new disclaimer near option 2

Comment: I am more concerned about option 1. Because that is much better than option 2. Also, OP is supposed to change the argument type for option 1 not for option 2. I think that disclaimer should be part of option 1.

Comment: @KunalPuri Not sure what you're saying

Comment: `void processArgs(int argc, char** argv);` This is the declaration of function used by OP. So, What I want to say is that for option 1, you have to change it to `void processArgs(int argc, const char** argv);`. For option 2, I think `void processArgs(int argc, char** argv);` will work just fine as far as compilation is concerned.

Comment: @KunalPuri Oh I didn't see that before. okay, removed the first one.

Comment: One more thing. If I try to edit `argv` in processArgs(), Are you really sure that the program won't crash? In the other answer, It won't crash for sure. Not sure in your case.

Comment: @KunalPuri Not sure. However, OP does not mention intent to modify `argv`. If, as its name suggests, it is to process arguments passed to the program, I don't think that's something to worry about

Comment: @KunalPuri Also, OP declared `cwd` as an array of non-modifiable `char *` pointers in his post. This preserves his intent

Comment: It might be done for testing purposes also. Also, OP should have declared `const char **` in processArgs() if OP had the intent of not modifying the argument.

Comment: @KunalPuri We may never know. Speculating about intent is pointless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187538/discussion-between-govind-parmar-and-kunal-puri).